# setState() behind nativeEvent.text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm calling a function in the `onChange` property of a `TextInput` in order to update a state when the input changes. Here it is:

```
onInputChanged(event) {
    // Seems to be a delay before updating the nicknameString (1 typing late)
    this.setState({ nicknameString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    console.log(this.state.nicknameString);
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);
}
```

However... the first log displays the string with one typing late, i.e when I type `Asdf`, the first log will displays `Asd` when the second one will display `Asdf`. Then, if I delete the f, the first log will display `Asdf` (one typing late) when the second one will display `Asd` (as it should).

Is there any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging the value of `this.state. nicknameString` before it has had a chance to register.

To immediately inspect the state after `setState`, you can do a few things, here are a couple of examples:

1: Log out state in callback after `setState` has completed:

```
this.setState({
    nicknameString: text
}, () => {
    console.log('nicknameString:', this.state.nicknameString)
})
```

2: Call setImmediate to queue the function behind whatever I/O event callbacks that are already in the event queue.

```
this.setState({
    nicknameString: text
})
setImmediate(() => console.log('nicknameString:', this.state.nicknameString))
```

I've set up examples with both [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/WRUcVw).

https://rnplay.org/apps/WRUcVw